# Google Spreadsheets - Combining a Filter with Index(Match))... sort of

Tags: google-sheets

I've been keeping a log of something for a game which regularly updates. For the most part, I've been handling a lot of it manually and slowly over time I add in some automation to reduce the burden of manual input (and reduce the chance of data entry error).

Specifically, I'm trying to find a way to streamline the process on the following sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nbP0VgXjHozZikZFejERfw_dkilj26pyfhK29uaPAIQ/edit#gid=688163851

How this sheet is set up right now:

1. I manually enter the "Item Name" when something new is added
2. I manually enter the "Weapon Type" when something new is added
3. I manually enter in the "Date" when something new is added and when it returns

The first step I could automate relatively easily with something like this:

```
=FILTER('DUCAT COST HISTORY'!A2:A,'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!B2:B="Weapon")
```

The second step could similarly be automated if I added another column to the 'DUCAT COST HISTORY'! sheet which further specified the item.

**What I'm having trouble with is how to automate entering the dates on this particular sheet.** And the other sheets similar to this one.

The way things work right now is I use a script to grab the new inventory from a .php the developers put together and that information goes in 'TEST SHEET, PLEASE IGNORE'!. After that, the 'DUCAT COST HISTORY'! sheet will automatically update for all existing items, though I still have to manually add new items to the bottom of the list (not a big problem).

What I want is a formula which can look at a range and then return from a different range. Ex.: Let's say I want to look up the "Mara Detron" - I know it's appeared on 7 different dates through the simple use of `=COUNTA(F2:2)` on the 'DUCAT COST HISTORY'! sheet.

When I try to use INDEX(MATCH()), it's only going to return the value of the cell specified, so I can't use it to check the whole row. The best solution I can come up with is to manually match the item to its respective row and then run the filter like this:

```
=FILTER('DUCAT COST HISTORY'!F1:1,NOT(ISBLANK('DUCAT COST HISTORY'!F__:__)))`
```

Where `_` would be the corresponding row value.

That's about as far as I got in automating them, though. Is there a way to get the formula to automatically match the corresponding row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET` with `MATCH` to get the right row for the filter condition:

```
=
FILTER(
  'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!$I$1:$1,
  NOT(
    ISBLANK(
      OFFSET(
        'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!$I$3:$3,
        MATCH(A2, 'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!$A$3:$A, 0) - 1,
        0,
        1
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This goes in the cell `C2` and you just propagate it downwards. To tolerate empty cells you can add `IF`:

```
=
IF(
  ISBLANK(A2),
  ,
  FILTER(
    'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!$I$1:$1,
    NOT(
      ISBLANK(
        OFFSET(
          'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!$I$3:$3,
          MATCH(A2, 'DUCAT COST HISTORY'!$A$3:$A, 0) - 1,
          0,
          1
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

---

You were totally right about *the chance of data entry error*: you've used row 22 instead of row 32 for *Prisma Skana*. :)